# Understanding proof of the Proposition 8.10 in Gortz's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 8.10 and some question arises :

[image]

[image]

( Explanation of some notation : In the statement (iii) of the Proposition, $\mathcal{U}(s)$ means that $\mathcal{U}_s \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \kappa(s)$  (his book p.170). And in the statement (iii), $\iota_s \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)}$(stalk of homomorphism) is more correct notation. )

I'm trying to understand the underlined statement. Why the underliend statement is true?

My first attempt is as follows :

First, note that if we can show $r' \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} = r_0$, then since $r_0$ is a left inverse of $i_0$, $$(r' \circ i) \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} = (r' \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}})\circ (i \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}) = r_0 \circ i_0 = id_{N/\mathfrak{m}N}$$

So we are done. So it suffices to show that  $r' \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} = r_0$.

Let $\pi_1 : N \to N/\mathfrak{m}N$ and $\pi_2 : M \to M/\mathfrak{m}M$ be the natural projections. Then we have $\pi_1 \circ r' = r_0 \circ \pi_2$, as the above image. So, $ (\pi_1 \circ r') \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} = (r_0 \circ \pi_2) \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}$, so that $(\pi_1 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}) \circ (r' \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}) = (r_0 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}) \circ (\pi_2 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}) $.

My question is,

Q. 1) Note that the codomains of the $\pi_1 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} $, $\pi_2 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}$ are $(N/\mathfrak{m}N)\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}$, $(M/ \mathfrak{m}M)\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}$ respectively. Then first question is, each are isomorphic to $M/ \mathfrak{m}M$ and $N/\mathfrak{m}N$ respectively?

Q. 2) If the question Q.1) is true, then each $\pi_1 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} $ and $\pi_2 \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}}$ are identity?

If these questions are true, then we maybe show $ r' \otimes id_{A/\mathfrak{m}} = r_0$ upto the isomorphisms in the question Q.1).

Is this argument works? If not, is there any other way to show the underlined statement? I want to understand this statement rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While for funtorial properties it may be advantageous to regard $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ as $M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}$, it unnecessariyl complicates things in computations. All that is needed for the underlined statement is the following commutative diagram:
[image]

This is automatic from the construction, and literally what the underlined statement means.

Now for your questions:

In general, if $I\subseteq A$ is any ideal, and $M$ any $A$-module, then $M\otimes_A(A/I)\cong M/(IM)$ via the natural map $m\otimes(a+I)\mapsto am+IM$. So yes, since $\mathfrak{m}(M/\mathfrak{m}M)=0$, we have a natural isomorphism $(M/\mathfrak{m}M)\otimes_A(A/\mathfrak{m})\cong M/\mathfrak{m}M$, given by $(m+\mathfrak{m}M)\otimes(a+\mathfrak{m})\mapsto am+\mathfrak{m}M$

For your second question, yes they are indeed the identity under the above identification: $\pi_1\otimes_A\operatorname{id}_{A/\mathfrak{m}}$ maps $m\otimes (a+\mathfrak{m})$ to $(m+\mathfrak{m}M)\otimes(a+\mathfrak{m})$, and both are identified with $am+\mathfrak{m}M$ inside $M/\mathfrak{m}M$.

Comment: Wow, I got it. Thanks !~~